# VBA, How do i hide entire Rows and entire Columns if there are no data in each respectively?

Tags: vba

I am quite new to VBA. Both rows and columns have headers and i need to hide them if they do not have any data in each respectively.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick

```
Sub main()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstColumn, lastColumn, firstRow, lastRow As Integer

    firstColumn = 1
    lastColumn = 10

    firstRow = 1
    lastRow = 10

    ' Check if column has any data beside its header
    For i = firstColumn To lastColumn
        Columns(i).Hidden = (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i)) < 2)
    Next i

    ' Check if row has any data beside its header
    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        Rows(i).Hidden = (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) < 2)
    Next i

End Sub
```